# How to loop through the variables of an entity in twig?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig

I'm using symfony2 and have accessed an entity using a doctrine query, which I then pass to my twig template. This entity has variables that I would like to loop through without having to explicitly name each one. Is there a way I can do this with twig or should I try a different design?

Comment: If you want to loop through all your entity fields, you may have to use reflection. But if I were you, I wouldn't do that. Indeed, trying another design is really a good idea...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Twig documentation says](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#for):

> A sequence can be either an array or an object implementing the
>   Traversable interface.

So it should work as long as you implement one of the [Traversable](http://php.net/Traversable) interfaces ([IteratorAggregate](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoraggregate.php) or [Iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php)).